# Unable to receive Google reports api push notifications

Tags: google-admin-sdk

We have an application where in we need to notify a URL whenever a new user is created in the Google Apps Domain. The notifying url is https://projectId.appspot.com/userWatcher. Have verified the domain in the app engine console as https://projectId.appspot.com even then unuable to receive the push notification messages to the notifying URL. Kindly help me out

Answer (score 0):

To use push notification make sure you do this things:

- Register the domain of your receiving URL.
  For example, if you plan to use https://example.com/notifications as your receiving URL, you need to register https://example.com.
- Set up your receiving URL, or "Webhook" callback receiver.
  This is an HTTPS server that handles the API notification messages that are triggered when a resource changes.
- Set up a notification channel for each resource endpoint you want to watch.
  A channel specifies routing information for notification messages. As part of the channel setup, you identify the specific URL where you want to receive notifications. Whenever a channel's resource changes, the Reports API sends a notification message as a POST request to that URL.

For more information check this [page](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/push#registering-your-domain).